# Django rest framework websockets auto update

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework for my API,and vue for frontend, and, it is possible to auto update my frontend state when I changed something ?Its totally basic vue and django code, just for example

Vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="numbers">{{ state.numbers }}</div>
    Number pk <input type="text" v-model="state.pk" /> Number value
    <input type="text" v-model="state.inputValue" />
    <button v-on:click="changeNumber">change !</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { reactive, onMounted } from "vue";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      numbers: [],
      inputValue: 1,
      pk: 1,
    });
    function changeNumber() {
      const data = {
        number: state.inputValue,
      };
      console.log(data);
      axios.patch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/number-update/${state.pk}/`, data);
    }
    onMounted(() => {
      axios
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/numbers-list/")
        .then((res) => (state.numbers = res.data));
    });
    return {
      changeNumber,
      state,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

How it is in browser
[image]

and I want to, when I click change button, auto update backend data,without refreshing.

Backend

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Number


class NumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Number
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .serializers import NumberSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Number


class NumbersList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Number.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NumberSerializer


class NumberUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Number.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NumberSerializer
```

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from mynumbers.views import NumbersList, NumberUpdate
urlpatterns = [
    path('numbers-list/', NumbersList.as_view(), name='numbers-list'),
    path('number-update/<int:pk>/', NumberUpdate.as_view(), name='number-update'),
]
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Number(models.Model):
    number = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,
                                 decimal_places=2)
```

How can I use websockets or any another technology to do it ?
Sorry for my english.

Comment: You should be able to use axios that you're already using in your project, to make an AJAX-style API call when the change button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update data after patch method

```
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      numbers: [],
      inputValue: 1,
      pk: 1,
    });
    const updateData = () => {
      return axios
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/numbers-list/")
        .then((res) => (state.numbers = res.data));
    }
    function changeNumber() {
      const data = {
        number: state.inputValue,
      };
      console.log(data);
      axios
        .patch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/number-update/${state.pk}/`, data)
        .then(updateData);
    }
    onMounted(updateData);
    return {
      changeNumber,
      state,
    };
  },
};
```